# symfony2 hwioauthbundle correct configuration

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I tried to use hwioauth bundle to authenticate through salesforce, but I'm not able to run whi configuration.
I get the following message:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration for path "security.firewalls.secured_area": The check_path "/login_check" for login method "oauth" is not matched by the firewall pattern "^/demo/secured/".
```

I'm afraid I didn'y understand docs or they are lacking details about routing configuration...

My very basic configuration for /demo/secured_area is:

**routing.yml:**

```
hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:    /demo/secured/login

salesforce_login:
    pattern:  /demo/secured/check-salesforce
```

**config.yml:**

```
hwi_oauth:
    connect:
        confirmation: true
    firewall_name: secured_area

    resource_owners:
        salesforce:
            type:          salesforce
            client_id:     xxx
            client_secret: xxx
```

**security.yml:**

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        anonymous: ~
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                salesforce:    "/demo/secured/check-salesforce"
            login_path:        /login
            use_forward:       false
            failure_path:      /login

            oauth_user_provider:
                oauth: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/demo/secured/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

So I was wondering which configuration should be used.

Comment: Strange, this config is correct. Perhaps remove the trailing slash from the `firewalls.secured_area.pattern` path ?

Comment: Wait, it's using `/login_check` as the value. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: finally I managed to make it work, starting with a simple configuration and a demo controller.